# Bind string[] to XAML using TwoWay

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I've a Model and I receive a property called `birth` in this format

`birthday, birthplace`

I've set this inside the Model

```
private string _birth;
/// <summary>
/// Birth information in format: birthday, birthplace
/// </summary>
[Column("birth")]
[JsonProperty("birth")]
public string Birth
{
    get { return this._birth; }
    set
    {
        this._birth= value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("BirthData");
    }
}
```

Also I've set a public `modifier` like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Split the birth data if exists
    /// </summary>
    public string[] BirthData
    {
        get { return this.Birth?.Split(',');  }
    }
```

In my XAML file I've setup everything correctly for my Model, except that I can't understand how I can use TwoWay binding on something like this. Below you will find the extract of the XAML for this particular property

```
<Label x:Name="BirthdayLabel" Content="Nato Il" />
<DatePicker x:Name="BirthdayDateTimePicker" SelectedDate="{Binding selectedModel.BirthData[0], Mode=TwoWay}"></DatePicker>
<Label x:Name="BirthplaceLabel" Content="Nato A"/>
<TextBox x:Name="BirthplaceTextBox" Text="{Binding selectedModel.BirthData[1], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Of course this is not working properly because I'll ended up with `selectedModel` using the old information about the property even though the binding works as expected, I think that the TwoWay binding doesn't work with an Array of data like that.

I cannot change the DataSource and I've to find a method to use one textbox and one date picker and resemble together inside my ViewModel, which doesn't have much except a single method called `Update()` which take the current selectedModel.

Comment: Have you thought about using **validation** attributes on `Birth` instead?

Comment: @MikeEason I'm learning WPF and MVVM pattern, can you link me some source or explain to me what do you mean with validation attributes?

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat) you go. You could bind to `Birth` (which will have some validation attributes on it), if the user enters anything erroneous, you can simply pop that message up.

Comment: @MikeEason thanks, so removing the `BirthData` property and instead using `Birth` + validations. That's quite nice honestly :-) Kudos

Comment: @Claudio,  You want two way binding,right. Validation is interesting, but it is not your question, right ?

Comment: You can't two-way bind to primitives inside of an array or a collection. You can only two-way bind to properties.  The solution below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ViewModel is about preparing the data for the View**

So I suggest that you **split and parse the data** in the View Model and expose two properties for `BirthDate` and `BirthPlace` :

```
class Person
{
    private string _birth;
    public string Birth{
        get { return this._birth; }
        set
        {
            this._birth = value;
            SplitBirthIntoBirthDayAndBirthPlace();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private DateTime _birthday;
    public DateTime Birthday{
        get { return _birthday; }
        set
        {
            _birthday = value;
            ReComputeBirth();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    // Same for Birthplace ...
    private void ReComputeBirth(){
        // ... Format the data as expected ...
        _birth = _birthday + ", " + _birthplace;
    }
    private void SplitBirthIntoBirthDayAndBirthPlace()
    {
        String[] values = _birth.Split(',', ' ');
        // ... really make the parse here to fill _birthplace and _birthdate...
    }
    // ....
}
```

And the binding is simpler:

```
    <DatePicker x:Name="BirthdayDateTimePicker"
                SelectedDate="{Binding selectedModel.Birthday, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="BirthplaceTextBox"
             Text="{Binding selectedModel.Birthplace, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Are you a wizard?
Joke aside this solution seems to fit my problem better then validations, where's birthplace ?

Comment: Grazie, non sono un "wizard". I just repeat ViewModel is just about preparing the data for the GUI, and exposing properties.

Comment: I see, I'm trying to learn MVVM "the right way" and this challenge is driving me crazy, thanks for the help. I'm implementing a solution based on your answer.

Comment: @Emmanuek DURIN this solution is sleek and cool. Can you suggest me books/sites/blog/videos to learn MVVM the right way please ?

Comment: I ve got only one book to advise "Programming WPF: Chris Sells, Ian Griffiths" that is a very thick , complete book - long to read reference book. You don' have to read it all. There are some very advanced topics. But everything is very well explained. Despite the good databinding pages, there is no section about MVVM.

Comment: And if you are fluent in french I recorded  about 15h of video about WPF, it is a commercial product : http://www.alphorm.com/tutoriel/formation-en-ligne-wpf-avec-visual-studio-2013-70-511

Comment: Sorry no French, only English, Italian and Russian ahah. Thanks for the book tho.